# Missing all SDK Platforms

Tags: android, eclipse

Couple of weeks ago I was working on android application. Everything was working fine. I have updated my eclipse with all the versions of android sdk. Starting from 1.* to 4.0.3. Today I opened my project to make some changes in that. And I found only 4.0.3 platform. And all my projects have hundreds of errors even my AVD is showing with red cross on it.

Can any one please tell me what is it? How come I miss my all installed sdk platforms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure your eclipse android plugin pointing to correct SDK path.

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally deleted the Android SDK folder it would stop all your code fro working. Try resetting up you path. In eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> Android. Then browse to the SDK folder in the SDK location target textbox.